# Ethernet to USB connector doesn't show up as an internet connection on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, usb, 20.04, internet, ethernet

I have recently bought a USB 3.0 Network Adapter by CableCreation. (Link [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B013G4C8RE)) and it had worked fine on Windows.  I then switched my operating system to Ubuntu 20.04 and the connection worked fine, for a while.  Now, I no longer see the connection in network settings at ALL, and even if I leave the dongle plugged in for a while I still don't see it.  I know the wire is okay because I have used it on my smart TV, and I have the proper drivers installed.  This is what it looks like when I write `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04f3:2494 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Touchscreen
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:58c2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 248a:8367 Maxxter Wireless Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

There was also no change when I ran `tail -f /var/log/syslog` without the dongle inserted, and then when I inserted it. Is there a way to get the connection to connect from the terminal by checking USB devices?  Is there something I am missing?  Please help.

Comment: Let's start by identifying the device. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Aslo, remove the device and run in a terminal: `tail -f /var/log/syslog`  Insert the device and paste the resulting output here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Get out of 'tail' with `Ctrl+c`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Is there a difference in the result of: `lsusb` either with or without the ethernet adapter?

Comment: No there is no difference.

Comment: Then I suspect that the device is defective. Does it show any signs of life with any other computers?